# FastAPI Project design problems (Authorization and URL Specifications)

Tags: python, authorization, fastapi, pydantic

I have got two design problems in my relativily big platform project. The first is one is where excatly should the endpoint authorization be placed in the project. Here is an example of a post request.
This request is sent to create an object that is related to a specific division (department), my question here is, should I get the division_id from the validator as a data field (pydantic schema) or as a path parameter?

```
assignmentsRouter = APIRouter(
    tags=["Assignments"],
    prefix="/{division_id}"
)

@assignmentsRouter.post("/assignments", status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
async def create_assignment(division_id: int, request: AssignmentValidator, db: Session = Depends(get_db),
                            user: UserModel = Depends(CheckPermission(FeaturePermissions.CREATE_ASSIGNMENT))):
    return Assignment.create(request, db, user, division_id)
```

Here is the creation function:

```
@classmethod
    def create(cls, request: BaseModel, db: Session, user: UserModel, division_id: int) -> Mapper | None:
        division = db.query(DivisionModel).filter_by(id=division_id).first()
        if division:
            return super().create(db, creator=user, division_id=division.id, **request.model_dump())
        raise HTTPException(status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, "division not found")
```

Here is the CheckPermission class as it is related to the second question:

```
class CheckPermission:
    def __init__(self, permission_to_check: int, core: bool = False):
        self.permission_to_check: int = permission_to_check
        self.core: bool = core

    async def __call__(self, request: Request,
                       user: UserModel = Depends(get_current_user),
                       db: Session = Depends(get_db)) -> UserModel:
        if self.core:
            self.check_user_permission(self.permission_to_check, user)
        else:
            division: DivisionModel | None = db.query(DivisionModel).filter_by(
                id=request.path_params["division_id"]).first()
            special_user = self.check_special_user_permission(self.permission_to_check, user, division, db)
            if special_user is not None:
                return special_user
            else:
                # Check role permission
                self.check_role_permission(self.permission_to_check, user, division, db)
                return user
```

As you can see, the division_id is also retreived from the path paramter and used to validate that the user in this specific division has the permission to do a specific action.

The whole point is, should I put the division_id in the pydantic model and authenticate in the logic of the endpoint or should I leave it as is and authenticate in its own dependancy?
Which is correct? why?

I tried both and they both work just fine, my question is what is the standard? how do I determine which is better for my application?

Comment: I don't know what the standard is but since it is being used for authentication purpose so for the separation of concerns, I would like to put it in headers and use in the `CheckPermission` class and instead of returning db model from that __call__ method, a different class consisting of user data and other permission data would have returned.